# Creating array in PHP. Really need solution for the underling problem

Tags: php

I have a string like below

```
 "\$tempArray['acct'][0]".$det["PATH"]
```

`$det["PATH"]` is an dynamically generated in each iteration.
something like this "`['e2']['2']['e2']['0']['e2']['0']`"

I want an array to be defined like this

```
$tempArray['acct'][0]['e2']['2']['e2']['0']['e2']['0'] = array ();
```

Since $det["path"] changes in every iteration . I need this array to be created for in each iteration with the name

I have tried the below code . But it creates and array with $tmpArray. not like this `$tempArray['acct'][0]['e2']['2']['e2']['0']['e2']['0']`

```
 if(!is_array("\$tempArray['acct'][0]".$det["PATH"])){
   $tArray = "\$tempArray['acct'][0]".$det["PATH"];
   var_dump($tArray );
   $tArray = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

The insecure way to do this is [`eval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

```
eval("\$tempArray['acct'][0]".$det["PATH"]." = array();");
```

The better way is to use the path as the key:

```
$tempArray['acct'][0][$det["PATH"]] = array();
```